# How to write logs data in a local txt file?

Tags: file, file-io, air

I have an AIR-app and  I want it to write down logs to a txt file in its application directory.

I have this class:

```
public class Logger 
    {


        public static function log(message:String):void
        {
            var logFile:File = File.applicationDirectory;
            logFile          = logFile.resolvePath("log/Logs.txt");

            var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(logFile, FileMode.APPEND);

            fileStream.writeUTFBytes("\n" + message);

            fileStream.close();
        }

    }

}
```

After installation my app has this file structure

log

--Logs.txt

META-INF

xml

airapp.exe

airapp.swf

mimetype

So the path I'm using is correct.
But no writes happen to the file!
Could you help me with that please?
Thanks

**Upd.** Ok, I'm stupid. I should have read documentation properly first.
You cannot edit data in application directory.

So I should use applicationStorageDirectory.

**But how can I create a file in that directory once (on app installation) and then append logs in it?**

Answer (score 1):

Try the following....

```
function saveLog(logStr:String):void
 {


   var myFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("my_logs.txt");
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    if(!myFile.exists){

     fs.open(myFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    }
    else{ 
     fs.open(myFile, FileMode.APPEND);
    }
    fs.writeUTFBytes("\n" + logStr);
    fs.close();
}
```

call this function on creation complete and then from where to add logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the real log than you should use third party installer rather than native run time of adobe air. Try Wixedit(opensource) or install aware .

You have to export your project into captive run time format that is provided in flash builder.

try this link

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/customize-setup-for-AIR-app-with-captive-runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 function saveLog(content:String):void
 {
    var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    data.writeMultiByte(content, "utf-8");
    file.save(data, "Logs.txt");
 }

 saveLog('testing :)');
```

To open and edit your log file, try to follow [this tutorial](http://www.adobeairtutorials.com/2009/01/28/adobe-air-read-and-write-file-system-%E2%80%93-part1/)